# RabbitMQ in spring boot with priority queue

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

My problem because I try to implement priority queue with rabbitMQ but its always random. Even when I set priority @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_MESSAGES, priority = "10").

I send 100 messages to two queus :

```
public void sendRequest() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            try {
                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ProducerConfig.QUEUE_MESSAGES2,
                        new MessageDTO("Subject Two", "content2"), message -> {
                            message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(Integer.valueOf(10));
                            return message;
                        });


                rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(ProducerConfig.QUEUE_MESSAGES,
                        new MessageDTO("Subject One", "content1"), message -> {
                            message.getMessageProperties().setPriority(Integer.valueOf(1));
                            return message;
                        });
                System.out.println("messages has been send");
            } catch (AmqpException ex) {
                System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

So I have two listeners :

```
    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_MESSAGES, priority = "1")
    public void receiveMessage(MessageDTO message) throws BusinessException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            System.out.println(message.getSubject());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE_MESSAGES2, priority = "10")
    public void receiveMessage2(MessageDTO message) throws BusinessException, InterruptedException {
        try {
            System.out.println(message.getSubject());
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception" + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My output is random like this :

```
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
Subject Two
Subject One
```

I need to receive all messages from first queue then receive messages from seconds queue. Can anybody help ?

I already even try with this in application.properties :

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.prefetch=1
```

My version is : RabbitMQ 3.8.12 Erlang 23.2.6

#EDIT
I set priority in producer config to queue and in sending request priority to messages but it deosnt helps
Producer config :

```
@Bean
    public Declarables fanoutBindings() {
        Queue messageQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(QUEUE_MESSAGES)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", DLX_EXCHANGE_MESSAGES)
                .withArgument("x-priority", Integer.valueOf(1))
                .build();
        Queue messageQueue2 = QueueBuilder.durable(QUEUE_MESSAGES2)
                .withArgument("x-dead-letter-exchange", DLX_EXCHANGE_MESSAGES)
                .withArgument("x-priority", Integer.valueOf(10))
                .build();
        Queue deadLetterQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(QUEUE_MESSAGES_DLQ).build();
        Queue parkingLotQueue = QueueBuilder.durable(QUEUE_PARKING_LOT).build();
        FanoutExchange deadLetterExchange = new FanoutExchange(DLX_EXCHANGE_MESSAGES);

        return new Declarables(
                messageQueue,
                parkingLotQueue,
                deadLetterQueue,
                messageQueue2,
                deadLetterExchange,
                BindingBuilder.bind(deadLetterQueue).to(deadLetterExchange));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `priority` property on `@RabbitListener` is the [consumer priority](https://www.rabbitmq.com/consumer-priority.html). Consumers with higher priority will receive messages when they are active, while lower priority consumers will only get messages when higher priority consumers block. This assumes those consumers are consuming from the same queue, which is not your case.

If you want to implement priority messages, you need to define a [Priority Queue](https://www.rabbitmq.com/priority.html) with a max priority and set the priority property when sending the message (messages without priority will be treated as 0 priority).

Comment: I already tried with priority in messages and in queues. It doesnt help :(

Comment: Are you reading from the same queue? How do you send the messages?

Comment: I think you have a basic misunderstanding; the two listeners are completely unrelated.

Comment: I use two listeners because by default there will be differetn objects in this queues.